Spring ResponseEntity<T> equivalent in quarkus-openapi-generator
I need the generated java code include both response body and headers.
I know there is return-response option in quarkus-openapi-generator to return javax.ws.rs.core.Response but that class is not generic and requires casting all the time.
Is there anything similar to spring ResponseEntity in quarkus?

Use RestResponse instead.
